# how to use .find properly in jquery for get value

Tags: jquery

Hello can someone know is it possible to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').delegate('#check-hide-empty-table', 'click', function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert("checked")
                $('table').find('tr td.test').parents('tr').hide();
            }
            else {
                alert("uncheck")
                $('table').find('tr td.test').parents('tr').show();
            }
        });
```

and php file like this

```
</script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped table-fixed tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <th><input type="checkbox" value="hide" id="check-hide-empty-table"> Hide Empty</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php
        $first = false;
        foreach ($data["data"] as $list) {
            $isfull = $list["Players"] == $list["MaxUsers"] ? true : false;
    ?>

        <tr class="tabClicker" data-tab="tabs-1" id="<?=$list["Id"];?>">
            <td class= "test"><?= $list["Players"]."/".$list["MaxUsers"];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

what i want to do is, i wanna create hidden chechbox function when **$list["player"] = 0** but i'm confuse how to that so i tried to use take value **.find(tr td.test)** and if **.find(tr td.test) = 0**, that table will be hidden

how to do that? this code now still error. thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that the `delegate()` method is deprecated. You should use `on()` instead. If you're using any version of jQuery older than 1.7 you'll need to upgrade it, ideally to at least 1.12.

You should also use the `change` event when dealing with radio buttons and checkboxes for better accessibility.

To solve your actual issue you can use `filter()`, like this:

```
$('#myTable').on('change', '#check-hide-empty-table', function() {
    $('table').find('tr td.test').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim() == "0";
    }).parents('tr').toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

In this example I negated the need for the `if` statement by providing the boolean value from the `checked` property to the `toggle()` method.

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5sk771yg/)

Comment: thanks man for your answer but i got problem because **<td class= "test"><?= $list["Players"]."/".$list["MaxUsers"];?></td>** have 2 value, result like 0/8 or 0/5 not only 0. i just wanna ask again, is that efficient if i make like this? `<td class= "test"><span><?= $list["Players"]?></span>/<?=$list["MaxUsers"];?></td>` now this code is work @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Yep - that's perfectly fine and how I'd fix it too.